# Elementor: Is it possible to show a page behind the header template?

Tags: html, css, templates, elementor

I use Elementor on the Website I'm currently working on. I have created the full-width header template, and the Wordpress home page. I would want to show this WP page, with its top being behind the header.

By default, Elementor shows the header at first, and then, at the bottom of the header, it shows the WP page. That's not the behavior I expect. I would want to show both the header and the top of the WP page. Then, after the header's height, the WP page continues to be shown of course.

But is it possible and how? I didn't find any useful information in https://docs.elementor.com/category/411-how-tos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the header in absolute position with a specified 100% width, both in custom css, works well.